# Inconsistency between the debugger and running the program

Tags: c, visual-studio-debugging

I have a pretty large program (that's why I won't show code), that has a `quit()` function that prints all errors and prints an exit message, no matter what happens in the program, it will reach the `quit()` function.
Problem is, when I run the program, sometimes it reaches said `quit()` method and prints the exit method, and sometimes it doesn't, it ends without printing the exit message. I don't get why this happens, and what's more weird is that when I debug the program, it always works.
I read that the debugger has certain features which allow for less crashes.

Can you tell me where comes the inconsistency and what should I do to fix it.

Note: My program is written in C, and I'm compiling with Visual Studio 2013 (C++).

Thanks.

SOLVED: The problem was that I access unallocated memory (I dynamically allocated, but not enough). Solution in my case was to realloc().

Comment: Impossible without reading the code ... or at least a part of it

Comment: Not uncommon, unfotunately. Typical reasons: 1. Debugging runs programs in debug mode, no optimization; that changes stack layouts and code and may hide errors. 2. Timing issues when debugging.

Comment: @SujithGunawardhane: Of course it's not reproducible in a condensed example. Don't yell.

Comment: @PeterSchneider So what can I do about it?

Comment: When you say "sometimes it doesn't", do you mean "Sometimes it doesn't reach the `quit` function" or do you mean "Sometimes the `quit` function runs but doesn't print anything"?

Comment: @RaymondChen How can I distinguish between the two? Also, I was testing things and it seems that if I have 11 or 9 or less program arguments the problem doesn't occur (haven't checked for higher numbers).

Comment: One thing to try is to debug an optimized program (change the build options for the debug configuration which you are building). The debugging won't work very well but it still may give you enough information to identify the problem. And then just do more "printf debugging". Or perhaps somebody finds the error.

Comment: A remark: `if (extension == ".huf")`will not work, you need to use strcmp().

Comment: Another remark is that there are libraries out there which parse command lines. That home cooked code would be buggy on anybody's first try.

Comment: If you assign e.g. `cryptoKey = optionParameters[i];` you change the local parameter cryptoKey, not the actual argument, the cryptoKey in main. You can either allocate space for main's cryptoKey, like `char cryptoKey[100];`, and strcpy to that address instead of overwriting it; or you can pass a pointer to the pointer and write to the char* itself like you are doing now: `initializeOptions( ..., char **cryptoKeyParam, ...) { *cryptoKeyParam = optionParameters[i]; ...}`, calling this from main with `initializeOptions(..., &cryptoKey, ...);`.

Comment: You could distinguish between the two by having the `quit` function intentionally crash when called. If the program crashes in the `quit` function, then you know it was called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out what was wrong, fileNames is allocated 2 places for char *, when I allocate more place then I give it names, then it works, I just need to realloc.

Answer (score 1):

You don't set main's cryptoKey in initializeOptions() as I discussed in a comment. (Instead you overwrite a parameter value.) If you later use that key (because a crypto method has been set), it will point to arbitrary memory.

Comment: Hm, I thought of that when I wrote it, but then it seemed to work then I figured it was ok and forgot about it... Well, we learn every day. Thank you very much.

Comment: Oh wait, now it works in release mode but doesn't in debug mode...

Comment: I also took the liberty and changed fileNames to work in the same manner.